# Convert video to audio using FFMPEG with android native c

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have integrated FFMPEG into my application and I want to convert videos to audio files,

But I want to do it using native implementation , (JNI)  I don't want to use ffmpeg scripts ,

I have already tried [this](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert video to audio. You can however extract and only store the audio sub-streams of an AVFormatContext. Pseudocode:

```
// look for the first auid substream, and save its index:
for (size_t i = 0; i < AvFormatContextInstance->nb_streams; ++i)
    if (AvFormatContextInstance->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        streamindex = i;
```

Now all you need to do is discard all other streams on other indexes and save AVPackets from the recognized audio stream.

Comment: thanks for the reply , is thr anyway to compress video using JNI. i ave already tried to convert it using FFMPEG scripts . but i want to  do it on JNI. is tnr any way to do it  .